# What is a nice, clean proof to show that a fair coin toss satisfies axioms of probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If we assume H=Heads T=Tails and we're dealing with a fair coin what is a good way we can show that Kolmogorov Axiom has been satisfied?

Answer (score 4):

There are only four possible events: $\emptyset$, $\{H\}$, $\{T\}$, $\{H,T\}$. The fair coin model assigns the respective probabilities $0,\frac12,\frac12,1$ to these. The first two axioms follow immediately, the third .., well there are just a few ways to have a collection of mutually exclusive events.